# INVISIBLE button after taking a picture from camera

Tags: javascript, android

this is an example to take the picture.
Why button 3 does not INVISIBLE after shooting? 
What is the correct way to hide the button after taking a picture?
Please help with thanks.
    Note: I TRY IN galaxy 3 mini (18190) >> does not work

```js
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private static final int ACTIVITY_START_CAMER_APP = 0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    public  void showButton1(View view)  {
         EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText1.setText("1", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        showhideButton();
    }
    public  void hideButton2(View view)  {
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText1.setText("0", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
       showhideButton();
    }
    public  void showhideButton0(View view)  {
       showhideButton();
    }
    public  void showhideButton()  {
        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        int val = Integer.parseInt(editText1.getText().toString().trim());
        if (val == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "hide Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
           else if (val ==0) {  Toast.makeText(this, "show Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
    public void takePhoto(View view) throws IOException {
        Intent callCameraApplicationIntent = new Intent();
        callCameraApplicationIntent.setAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        callCameraApplicationIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        startActivityForResult(callCameraApplicationIntent, ACTIVITY_START_CAMER_APP);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        EditText txt4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        if   (requestCode == ACTIVITY_START_CAMER_APP && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
           txt4.setText("1", TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
        }
        else { return;}
       showhideButton();
    }
    File createImageFile() throws IOException {
      File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image1");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        File folder2 = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image1/Original_Images");
        boolean success2 = true;
        if (!folder2.exists()) {
            success2 = folder2.mkdir();
        }
        File image = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image1/Original_Images/1.jpg");
       return image;
    }
}
```

```css
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
   />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="show Button3"
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="122dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:onClick="hideButton2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hide Button3"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:onClick="showButton1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:inputType="number"


        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="takePhoto"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="takePhoto"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="showhideButton"
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:onClick="showhideButton0"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try Switching INVISIBLE and VISIBLE in your if (val == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "hide Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);}
           else if (val ==0) {  Toast.makeText(this, "show Button3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            button3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

Comment: then change INVISIBLE >> GONE

Comment: Thank you for responding.
However, unfortunately method did not work
GONE Working TO Change the design of the Activity